# Emscripten SDL2_IMAGE_FORMATS='["png"] compile error OSError: [ WinError 193 ] %1 is not valid Win32 application

Tags: windows, powershell, sdl, emscripten

I followed the Emscripten with SDL2 from this website
https://lyceum-allotments.github.io/2016/06/emscripten-and-sdl2-tutorial-part-4-look-owl/

and [this](https://emscripten.org/docs/compiling/Building-Projects.html) official document of Emscripten
that suggest to use the flag with

```
-s SDL2_IMAGE_FORMATS='["bmp","png","xpm"]'
```

in Windows 10 64-bit  Emanscripten 1.38.29

However, if I compile with the flag

```
-s SDL2_IMAGE_FORMATS='["png"]'
```

It shows error

```
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

It is exactly the same problem as in the github [issue](https://github.com/emscripten-ports/SDL2_image/issues/4)

The comment suggests to replace command

```
SDL2_IMAGE_FORMATS='["png"]' //with SDL2_IMAGE_FORMATS="[""png""]"
```

also I tested with

```
SDL2_IMAGE_FORMATS=["png"]
```

or

```
SDL2_IMAGE_FORMATS=[png]
```

or

```
SDL2_IMAGE_FORMATS=['png']
```

or

```
SDL2_IMAGE_FORMATS="['png']"
```

or

```
SDL2_IMAGE_FORMATS=\"["png"]\"
```

or

```
SDL2_IMAGE_FORMATS=\"[\'png']\"
```

However, I still have exactly the same compile error

Comment: Likely cause is that you are running a 64 bit process on a 32 bit OS?

Comment: how could I fix the problem I use windows 64bit but I have no idea emcc is 32 bit or 64 bit. other works are compiled OK

Answer (score 3):

In windows you must type `SDL2_IMAGE_FORMATS = "[""png""]"`